# Irregular behavior in SharePoint Designer based workflows

Tags: workflow, site-template, site-collection, designer-workflow

I am using SharePoint Designer 2010 to build list workflows.

However, workflows that I have built and tested are unpredictably disappearing from the list of WFs available to run in the browser UI. They are still there in SharePoint Designer and are both published and checked in and do not report any errors from the "Check for Error" function in SPD, but when I go to the list and select "Workflows" from the dropdown on an item, I get to the Start a New Workflow screen and only one of the three is there(even though Completed Workflows still shows history for the disappeard ones.)

This is intermittent (they have disappeared and then re-appeared) but I haven't observed any predictable pattern to the behavior and don't know how to make the lost ones come back. This makes building and testing workflows almost impossible.

I have re-published and re-checked in all the WFs again (as I had defintely done before), and then (breifly) all three appeared. I hit refresh again a few minutes later, and now there are only two. I have no idea why the third one disappeared again after a few minutes as I took no action after that.

**details of the workflow and logs**

The solution we are trying to put in place requires WFs attached to a list to create a new item in a doclib on the same site and copy over the contents of column fields from the list item to the new doc metadata. I know this is possible and have done it before, but when I started testing this (same WF’s you were looking at that are disappearing) I was getting a strange error.

The behavior is:

1. A new doc is in fact created, but
2. The assigned variables are not passed to it, and
3. There is the following WF error:

   `3/14/2012 5:05 PM  Error   <image005.png>
   System Account
   The workflow could not create the list item. Make sure the list exists and the user has permissions to add items to the list.   Unknown error`

   `3/14/2012 5:05 PM  Error   <image005.png>
   System Account
   An error has occurred in Create New from DocLib.`

… which is strange, because it does in fact create the new item, it just dies immediately after that, before it can pass the variables to its new baby.

**other steps taken**

We set up a blank site and activated all of the same out-of-the-box features as the site collection in question (minus the custom features). The erratic behavior is not present on this site collection. They are hosted on the same farm.

We tried creating a new site from the problematic site template and had the same trouble.

Where do I start looking for details of this behavior?